# How to combine a larger dataframe with a smaller dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr

One data frame `df` contains 72 values corresponding to 4 variables A-D each. Another `df2` contains four values corresponding to A-D. I want to combine the two dataframes columnwise such that each row in `df` has the corresponding value from `df2`

I was going to use the ifelse function on `df` for the values. But it's too tedious to write so many lines of code. Is there an easier way to do this?

```
library(truncnorm)
x <- c(1:288)
sp <- rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each = 72)

df <- data.frame(x,sp)

x2 <- c(1,2,3,4)
sp <- rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each = 1)

df2 <- data.frame(x2,sp)


#Finaldata set

x  sp  x2
1  A   1
2  A   1
3  A   1
...
288 D 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just a left join?

```
dplyr::left_join(df,df2,by = 'sp')
```